# Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with vim input

Tags: neovim

I'm lazy and wanted to write a simple vim function where I just have to insert file name patterns to browser sync instead of the whole command. The problem is the variable name itself is outputted, not the input information. What am I doing wrong?

```
function! BrowserSyncC()
    let name = input("")
    :split | terminal browser-sync start --server --files name
endfunction
```

Comment: The variable name can't be used like that. See `:help :execute` and `:help expr_.`.

Comment: Thank you @romainl , I update to this:
` execute ':split | terminal browser-sync start --server --files' name `
This is working!

Answer (score 1):

To use a variable inside a command, use `execute` command to combine them:

```
    let name = input("")
    execute ":split | terminal browser-sync start --server --files " . name
```